# Selenium making a list with the get_attributes method

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get random wikipedia articles with the wikipedia API and then get all their href links which I did by:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
```

Then I made:

```
for elem in elems:
    elements = []

    elements.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

In order to only get the href links from the received list with the previously executed command. I only got a single link which is:

```
['https://www.mediawiki.org/']
```

I tried to do:

```
for elem in elems:
    elements = []
    elements.extend(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

Which resulted in this output:

```
['h', 't', 't', 'p', 's', ':', '/', '/', 'w', 'w', 'w', '.', 'm', 'e', 'd', 'i', 'a', 'w', 'i', 'k', 'i', '.', 'o', 'r', 'g', '/']
```

Clearly put: I want to take all href links from a random wikipedia article then put them in a single list called elements which I will later use for a for loop.

Thanks in advance.

Rest of my code if it is needed:

```
import wikipedia
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

#This will get a random wikipedia article
random_article = wikipedia.random(1)
#Get the articles URL
url = wikipedia.page(random_article).url

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    elements = []
    elements.extend(elem.get_attribute("href"))

print(elements)
```

Comment: Thx for accepting my ans as the best ans! Can u also upvote my ans? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialise the `elements` list outside the `for` loop, so this is how `for` loop should look like:

```
elements = []

for elem in elems:
    elements.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

Full code:

```
import wikipedia
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

#This will get a random wikipedia article
random_article = wikipedia.random(1)
#Get the articles URL
url = wikipedia.page(random_article).url

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
elements = []
for elem in elems:
    elements.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))

print(elements)
```